# How to ensure some mandatory and some optional elements under complextype in xml?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am facing problems in making a complex element, which allows both optional as well as mandatory elements.
For the xml below, say h2 is mandatory, while h1 is optional, and the order does not matter.

Case 1:

```
<root>
<h1/>
<h2/>
</root>
```

Case 2:

```
<root>
<h2/>
</root>
```

Case 3:

```
<root>
<h2/>
<h1/>
</root>
```

XSD:

```
<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
               <xs:element name="h1" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
                <xs:element name="h2" minOccurs="1" />
           </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

the third case above fails in this xsd, but such case is valid.
I need an xsd that is valid for all the above mentioned cases.

Comment: could you tell me if `<root><h1/><h2/><h1/><h2/></root>` should be valid?

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that what you want is:

> to make h2 occur atmost 1, while h1 can occur as many times as
>   possible

You could use this XSD in which you are defining that a XML would be valid if its content is something like (RegExpr) `<root><h1/>*<h2/><h1/>*</root>`.

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="root">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xsd:element name="h1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element name="h2" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="h1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>        
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

---

**Valid XML examples:**
1)

```
<root>
  <h1/>
  <h1/>
  <h2/>
  <h1/>
</root>
```

2)

```
<root>
  <h1/>
  <h2/>
</root>
```

---

**Invalid XML example:**
Two `<h2/>` Elements.

```
<root>
  <h2/>
  <h1/>
  <h2/>
</root>
```

No `<h2/>` Element.

```
<root>
  <h1/>
  <h1/>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks, but you cannot have element with the same name defined twice inside one element. This definition is not correct.

Comment: Defining two elements with the same name within a given content model can be error-prone because it's subject to a lot of rules, but it's not illegal.  The schema given in the answer (as it now stands) looks legal to me, and it's accepted by the validators I've tried (Xerces J and Saxon EE).